# UIStackView animation breaks functionment

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uistackview

I try to make an animation inside a horizontal stack view.
When you click on a button, its associated label is displayed and the other are hidden.

When I do that without animation, it works fine.

But when I add `UIView.animateWithDuration`, it breaks after several clicks.

I don't understand why...

Here is my code without animation. All the buttons and labels are in an horizontal stack view, with Alignement is Fill, Distribution is Fill Equally and spacing is 5 :

```
@IBOutlet weak var itemLabel1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var itemLabel2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var itemLabel3: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var itemLabel4: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var itemLabel5: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var itemButton1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var itemButton2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var itemButton3: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var itemButton4: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var itemButton5: UIButton!

@IBAction func clickOnItemButton(sender: UIButton) {
    // hide all other labels
    switch sender {
    case itemButton1:
        hideAllExcept(itemLabel1)
    case itemButton2:
        hideAllExcept(itemLabel2)
    case itemButton3:
        hideAllExcept(itemLabel3)
    case itemButton4:
        hideAllExcept(itemLabel4)
    case itemButton5:
        hideAllExcept(itemLabel5)
    default:break
    }
}

func hideAllExcept(currentLabel: UILabel?) {
    for iLabel in [itemLabel1, itemLabel2, itemLabel3, itemLabel4, itemLabel5] {
        if iLabel == currentLabel {
                iLabel.hidden = false
        } else {
                iLabel.hidden = true
        }
    }
}
```

To enable animation, I replace this last function by :

```
func hideAllExcept(currentLabel: UILabel?) {
    for iLabel in [itemLabel1, itemLabel2, itemLabel3, itemLabel4, itemLabel5] {
        if iLabel == currentLabel {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) { () -> Void in
                iLabel.hidden = false
            }
        } else {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) { () -> Void in
                iLabel.hidden = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the result with and without animation :

[image: with animation]

[image: without animation]